# Send user location flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am trying to create a messaging app in flutter, and I want to let my user select a location on a map where the pointer is initialized at his location and I want the coordinates to be returned to an other page.
How can I do so using flutter_map?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) to get the user's location.

Here's a snippet of how that can be done

```
Position? position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
```

Although you might need to check permissions and handle different scenarios, I'm just keeping it simple, you can check the "read me" of the package.

Then depending on how you wrote your code for the map, you just need to use the position gotten

```
LatLng? _initialPosition = LatLng(position!.latitude, position!.longitude);
CameraPosition? _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
  target: _initialPosition!,
  zoom: 14.4746,
);

GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition!,
      ....
    ),
```

You can also use the position to draw your marker, I hope this helps.